# How are text images processed by Facebook?

Tags: facebook, image-processing

This code is processed as goku image on FB chat:

```
[[236823566443944]][[236823583110609]][[236823586443942]][[236823596443941]][[236823609777273]]
[[236823629777271]][[236823636443937]][[236823649777269]][[236823663110601]][[236823673110600]]
[[236823683110599]][[236823686443932]][[236823696443931]][[236823699777264]][[236823709777263]]
[[236823716443929]][[236823733110594]][[236823736443927]][[236823749777259]][[236823753110592]]
[[236823756443925]][[236823759777258]][[236823769777257]][[236823779777256]][[236823783110589]]
[[236823789777255]][[236823793110588]][[236823796443921]][[236823806443920]][[236823809777253]]
```

How FB creates image from this? I found the code on [symbols-n-emoticons](http://www.symbols-n-emoticons.com/p/facebook-emoticons-list.html) in comments below, copied&pasted into FB chat and - black magic - the image was there.

Comment: To the close voter: Unclear what am I asking? Really? I just want to know how FB creates image from this. This is a valid question here, right?

Comment: The question is pretty interesting I have already googled it for more than 30 minutes but I can't find an answer)) Can you explain the case in more details(where did you see this?)

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan I updated the question with the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took your example and did some testing. If yout right click on the image in chat and look at it URL, you can find following:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/227547_236823636443937_1841629131_n.jpg

It's one tile from the goku image. The middle part of the URL corresponds to one value in you code. So this code are actually shortcuts to images stored on FB servers, and the chat window simply replaces the code with image.

I think it could be due to latest update in FB, which allows you to attach images directly to posts.

[EDIT]
I have tried several other images and it worked for all images hosted `akamaihd.net` aka Facebook hosting. Just grab the secod number and past it in chat in double brackets.

The image is always resized to 16x16px, hence the code for Goku is so long, it's actually made from tiles.

Comment: Great answer! I guess that the 16x16px image was originally supposed to be user defined smiley and people use it different way than FB expected.